# How to refresh a compositeView Marionette

Tags: backbone.js, refresh, marionette

Using Backbone + Marionette, how do I refresh the view in the initialize method of a CompositeView?

This is my code:

```
View.RegionProofUploadView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        template : regionProofsTpl,
        tagName : "div",
        className : "panel panel-default",
        childView : View.ProofUploadView,
        childViewContainer : "div.pieces",
 });
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `refresh`..? initialize is called when a new view is created, why would you want to `refresh` a `fresh` view?

Comment: because the composite View depends on item views. In the initialize method i will test if this .model.status="validated"  ==> refresh the composite view

Comment: So what do you mean by `refresh`..?

Comment: reload to change it's status if the status of it's child has been changed to be "validated"

Comment: I'm confused here. You said *"i need to refresh it in the initialize method"* - initialized is called when a *new* (fresh) view is created. Which means it probably doesn't even have a child. did you mean to manually invoke `initialize` at a later point of time..?

Comment: Composite View will maintain the child Item Views for a given collection automatically. Simply add or remove items from the collection, and the Composite View will refresh the list for you.

Comment: @Justinas thanks for your help i used the same logic as you've proposed except i used collectioEvents instead of childEvents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as I understand from your comments, you need to refresh (or in other words re-render) your view not in initialize (which as other guys pointed out has no purpose), but after the change event happens on the child model.

In that case you can use [marionette.js childEvents](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.3/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-childevents) to listen for that "change" event and act on it.

```
View.RegionProofUploadView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

    childEvents: {
        'change:status': 'onStatusChange',
    },

    onStatusChange: function (model, value, options) {
        this.render();
    },

});
```

This should (in theory) re-render your composite view if child model status attribute change.
Let me know if that was what you were expecting.